# Wi-Fi (RTL8821CE) на Ubuntu 16.04 не работает

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, networkx

Категорически отказывается работать wi-fi на ubuntu разных версий. Последний раз попробовал настроить wi-fi на ubuntu 16.04 по этой инструкции https://zalinux.ru/?p=4657. Все заработало. Через недели две опять перестал работать. Пробую воспользоваться этой же инструкцией, ничего не включается. Может, кто-нибудь знает, в чем проблема?

```
aleksandr@aleksandr-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-15AST:~$ lspci | grep Network
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

UPD:

```
nmcli device status

УСТРОЙСТВО  ТИП       СОСТОЯНИЕ      СОЕДИНЕНИЕ             
enp0s16u1   ethernet  подключено     Проводное соединение 1 
lo          loopback  не настроенно  --                     
wlp2s0      wifi      не настроенно  --
```

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers list` чё-нить показывает?

Comment: показал только ```rtl8821ce-dkms```

Comment: Ну и ты поставил этот пакет, ребутнул линукс и в network manager ничего не поехало?

Comment: @donRumata Добавил вывод ```nmcli device status```  в вопросе. Все остальные команды показывают, что все включено. Например, ```nmcli radio wifi```

Comment: Никогда не имел дел с nmcli. Но судя по выхлопу - вафля видится норм. В гуе нетверк менеджера сети появились?

Comment: @donRumata имеете ввиду названия сетей? Если это, то не появляется ни одно название сети. Как домашней, так и иной. Просто в какой-то момент, при включении ubuntu, wi-fi перестал быть виден, хотя во время предыдущей работы все было ок.

Comment: Так. Ну ок. А на свежем lts пашет? Я про 20.04. Там же и ядро сильно другое, а соответственно и драйвера.

Comment: @donRumata на какой-то из версий - 18.04 или 20.04 - когда-то, совершенно случайно удалось настроить wi-fi. После авто обновления виндовс, ubuntu целиком слетела. Ну а в целом, ситуация была намного хуже, чем с 16.04. То есть wifi на 20.04 не подавал вообще никаких признаков жизни

Comment: Тут пахнет багрепортом на лаунчпад.